# How to display custom processing message in JQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, datatables, message

i am using datatables api to display data in my asp.net4.0 application;

[**datatables**](http://datatables.net)

I have one column [ Delete ] to delete the row data.when i click on this link i send a jquery ajax request to delete the row from database.
I want to display a message such as [ Deleting record... ] to the end user until data deleted by server side processing.

I put a div on my page and write a message [ Deleting record... ] in a div when i click on delete link i display that message  but when delete operation complete it also display a message [ Processing... ](which is inbuilt message of datatables)  which looks like odd as two message are displaying.

What can i do better to display message to the end user.

**JSCode**

```
$('#tblVideoList .delete').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var oTable = $('#tblVideoList').dataTable();
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this.parentNode);
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos[0]);

    if (confirm('Are you sure want to delete the record.')) {
        $("#divDelete").show();
        var today = new Date();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "samplepage.aspx",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#divDelete").hide();
                oTable.fnDraw();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Thanks

Comment: where did you find those js files? i also have datatables but can't find the .js and .css files

Comment: which .js and .css files ur talking about

Comment: the datatables files which you can customize. liek the file above? how can i find that file and where is it located

Comment: from here **http://datatables.net/**

Answer (score 6):

You can change processing text by:

```
   $('#example').dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
           "sProcessing": "Deleting record..."
         }
    });
```

but you can always find processing div, replace the text and show it manually.

Comment: I tried solution with div, but it works only for first request, for over request datatables put original text from language, so better to use oLanguage setting :)